# Sum of marks in one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have MySQL table with structure like

```
lesson_id | task_id | user_id | mark
```

There can be many users and tasks on each lesson

I want to get 2 results :

1. sum of all marks for each user starting with big values (DESC order)
2. sum of all marks for one specified lesson for each user starting with big values (DESC order)

**Expected result 1.**

```
user_1 500
user_3 423
user_2 100
user_4 92
```

**Expected result 2.**

```
user_id |  mark | lesson_id 
user_3  |  423  |  2
user_2  |  100  |  2
user_4  |   92  |  2
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result!

Comment: *starting with big values*??

Comment: I assume "order by values desc".

Comment: sorry, i mean DESC order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with scaisEdge about the 1st question 
for the 2nd question you need to add filtering by lesson to the same query:

```
select user_id, sum(mark) sum_of_mark 
from your_table 
group by user_id 
where lesson_id = @lesson 
order by sum_of_mark DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Group by and order By DESC

for User

```
select user_id, sum(mark) sum_of_mark
from your_table 
group by user_id
order by sum_of_mark DESC;
```

For Task 
    select user_id, task_id,  sum(mark) sum_of_mark
    from your_table 
    group by user_id, task_id
    order by sum_of_mark DESC;